# How to achieve Combination of both singlepage and multipage routing in same app in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

- I have a two main route components Home page and about page.
- Home page component contains two inner routes homeinner1 and
  homeinner2 with their respective links.

Code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Link to="/about"> Click to go to About Page </Link>
      </div>
      <br />
      Home Content
      <br />
      <br />

      <span> 
      <Link to="/homeinner1"> HomeInner 1 </Link> 
      </span> 
      
      &nbsp;
      
      <span> 
      <Link to="/homeinner2"> HomeInner 2 </Link>
      </span>

      <Route to="/homeinner1" component={Homeinner1} />
      <Route to="/homeinner2" component={Homeinner2} />
    </div>
  )
}

const Homeinner1 = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      Home Inner 1
    </div>
  )
}

const Homeinner2 = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      Home Inner 2
    </div>
  )
}

const About = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Link to="/"> Click to go to Home Page </Link>
      </div>
      About
    </div>
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/About" component={About} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

above is my code. on home page i set a link to go to the about page, on about page i set a link to home.

My problem is, both the homeinner 1 and homeinner 2 shows by default in home page, but i want to show only homeinner 1 route content and after clicking homeinner 2 link i want it to change to homeinner2, so i can switch it according.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have made a sample on [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-fast-m3s0i)

I created a separate route for **homeinner1** and **homeinner2**, just like:

```
   <BrowserRouter>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route
        path="/homeinner1"
        render={props => (
          <Home {...props}>
            <Homeinner1 />
          </Home>
        )}
      />
      <Route
        path="/homeinner2"
        render={props => (
          <Home {...props}>
            <Homeinner2 />
          </Home>
        )}
      />
      <Route path="/About" component={About} />
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, @Jojo i want to display the content of the homeinner1 by default, kindly edit the codesandox according to it, it will help me.

Comment: @MeenaLoshini, already updated. but it depends really on what you want. for now, i updated it for your simple usecase.